# Обработка ошибки telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Правильным ли будет вот так обработать непредвиденные ошибки с телеграм ботом?

```
while True:

try:

    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

В документации пишется что нельзя создавать больше 1 потока. Но чем это грозит?

> Warning: Do not call this function more than once!

Answer (score 1):

Бот может выдать ошибку, что нельзя запускать 2 бота с одним токеном одновременно.